# Default food property wording when translation not available

Tags: java, memory-optimization

I have food table having number of foods, each food can have specific properties in multiple languages (en, es) like name, description etc. But it is not sure if all of the properties are always present for preferred language of that user, so if they are not present for preferred language we can pick the properties from default language, So that we can be sure that we have data all the time to show on our app,

Here is my table structure

Food Table:

| food_id | visibility |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |

Properties Table:

| property_id | property_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name |
| 2 | description |
| 3 | short desc |

Food Properties Table:

| food_property_id | food_id | property_id | value | language_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | food name in en | en |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | food name in es | es |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | food description in en | en |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | food description in es | es |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | food short desc in en | en |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | food short desc in es | es |

Case 1:

Preferred language - es || Default language - en

All es properties are exists - fetch them all

Result:

Food Properties Table:

| food_property_id | food_id | property_id | value | language id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | food name in es | es |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | food description in es | es |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | food short desc in es | es |

Case 2:

Preferred language - es || Default language - en

Property Id 2 (description) and 3 (short desc) are missing for es, fetch from default language (en)

Food Properties Table:

| food_property_id | food_id | property_id | value | language_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | food name in es | es |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | food description in en | en |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | food short desc in en | en |

I hope the idea is clear to you now: We want to ensure that if specific property does not exists look for that property in default language, I
have to show this food list in app to multiple users with different languages, and it is not guaranteed that all the properties are present for that food. So its ok that we can show properties from default language, just to ensure that all the data on app always looks filled and not empty.

I am using Java for programming, Java preferred as I have used caching layer and filtering properties at that level, I tried a lot but used too many loops streams to compare each item with each other, so looking for optimized solution

```
public class FoodTest {

    public class FoodProperties {
        private String propertyCode;
        private String value;
        private String languageId;
        // getters, setters and constructor
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<FoodProperties> foodProperties = new ArrayList<>();
        FoodProperties p2 = new FoodProperties("1", "food name in es", "es");
        FoodProperties p1 = new FoodProperties("1", "food name in en", "en");
        FoodProperties p3 = new FoodProperties("2", "description in en", "en");
        FoodProperties p4 = new FoodProperties("2", "description in es", "es");
        FoodProperties p5 = new FoodProperties("3", "short desc in en", "en");
        FoodProperties p6 = new FoodProperties("3", "short desc in es", "es");
        FoodProperties p7 = new FoodProperties("3", "short desc in es", "pt");

        foodProperties.add(p1);
        foodProperties.add(p2);
        foodProperties.add(p3);
        foodProperties.add(p4);
        foodProperties.add(p5);
        foodProperties.add(p6);
        foodProperties.add(p7);

        String preferredLanguage = "es";
        String defaultLanguage = "en";

        Set<String> traversed = new HashSet<>();

        List<FoodProperties> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FoodProperties foodProperty : foodProperties) {
            String propertyCode = foodProperty.getPropertyCode();
            if (!traversed.contains(propertyCode)) {
                Optional<FoodProperties> food = foodProperties.stream()
                        .filter(f -> f.getLanguageId().equals(preferredLanguage)
                                && f.getPropertyCode().equals(propertyCode))
                        .findFirst();

                // preferred found use it else find default one
                if (food.isPresent()) {
                    result.add(food.get());
                } else {
                    Optional<FoodProperties> foodDef = foodProperties.stream()
                            .filter(f -> f.getLanguageId()
                                    .equals(defaultLanguage)
                                    && f.getPropertyCode().equals(propertyCode))
                            .findFirst();

                    // default found use it else find any other language
                    if (foodDef.isPresent()) {
                        result.add(foodDef.get());
                    } else {
                        Optional<FoodProperties> foodoDefAndNoPref = foodProperties
                                .stream().filter(f -> f.getPropertyCode()
                                        .equals(propertyCode))
                                .findFirst();
                        if (foodoDefAndNoPref.isPresent()) {
                            result.add(foodoDefAndNoPref.get());
                        }
                    }
                }
                traversed.add(propertyCode);
            }
        }
        for (FoodProperties foodPropertiesList : result) {
            System.out.println(foodPropertiesList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Explain what the code is doing.

Answer (score -1):

Approaching optimistically the use case to implement simplifies the result
thus while iterating over the `foodProperties` the `propertyCode` is added to `traversed` collection the `foodProperty` is further processed for the desired language checking the only two options of interest: actual `foodProperty` is in desired language or in default language.

With the assumption that the default language exists for every property following is a suggestion among various possible implementations:

```
for ( FoodProperty foodProperty : foodProperties ) {
    
    String propertyCode = foodProperty.getPropertyCode();
    if ( !traversed.add(propertyCode) ) { continue; }

    String propertyLanguage = foodProperty.getLanguageId();
    if ( preferredLanguage.equals(propertyLanguage) ) {
        result.add(foodProperty);
        continue;
    }
    
    FoodProperty defaultFoodProperty = foodProperties.stream()
                                                     .filter( f -> propertyCode.equals(f.getPropertyCode())
                                                                   && defaultLanguage.equals(foodProperty.getLanguageId()))
                                                     .findAny()
                                                     .get();
    result.add(defaultFoodProperty);
}
```

Comment: Hi the code is giving wrong output if i pass preferredLanguage = "es" and defaultLanguage = "en"; giving only en results ? it should give es results

Comment: It is generally a good idea not to answer questions that have comments that indicate that the question is off-topic. In this case the user may edit their question in a way that would invalidate the answer. If you user an AI to generate the answer, the answer must be deleted, the rules of the site do not allow generated answers.